# Proof by Induction help (inequality)

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

I need to prove if, 
$$a_1=1,\ a_2=2$$ and
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$
then
$$a_n\leq \left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{n-1}$$

Proof (by using strong induction):

As far as I go, is that I prove both bases where $n=1$ and $n=2$, so I then know that $a_{n+1}=2a_{n}+a_{n-1}$ where I follow (by using strong induction) that

$$a_{n+1}\leq 2\left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{n-1}+ \left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{n-2}$$ where it's where I get stuck, what I do is that I know the second term is a positive number, so I can remove it and the inequality remains

$$a_{n+1}\leq 2\left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{n-1}$$

then I know that $x^{n-1}=\left(\frac{x^n}{n} \right)$ so

$$a_{n+1}\leq \left(\frac{4}{5} \right)\left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{n}$$
And that's pretty much where I'm stuck, since I don't know if I can go on from there.

Thank for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can't* remove the second term.
$$a_{n+1}\leq 2\left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{n-1}+ \left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{n-2}$$
$$\leq \left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{n-2} [2\left(\frac{5}{2} \right) + 1] = 6 \left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{n-2} \\ < \left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^2 \left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{n-2} = \left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^n$$

This proves the induction hypothesis.

Comment: why? My logic was that since it is a positive number it is going to be less or equal than after I remove it

Comment: also, shouldn’t it be 6 instead of 3?

Comment: @DemianJimenez Nice catch!  Sorry for the careless mistake about $3$.  "less than or equal to $\le$" is a *binary* relation.  You need to put elements *around* it, like $6 \le 6.25$.

Answer (score 1):

The base is obvious.

Now, by the assumption of the induction we obtain:
$$a_n\leq2\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{n-2}+\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{n-3}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$2\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{n-2}+\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{n-3}\leq\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{n-1}$$ or
$$2\cdot\frac{5}{2}+1\leq\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

Using the ansatz $$a_n=q^n$$ we get the following explicit solution 
$$a_n=-\frac{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)
   \left(\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^n-\left(1+\sqrt{
   2}\right)^n\right)}{4 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}$$